# How to reset an animation with step?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

```js
myFun = () => {
    $('.test').animate({ now: 100}, {
        duration: 1000,
        complete: function() {
            now = 0;
        },
        step: function(now) {
            console.log(now);
        }
    });
}

myFun();
myFun();
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
<div class="test"></div>
```

I've this function:

```
myFun = () => {
    $('.test').animate({ now: 100}, {
        duration: 1000,
        step: function(now) {
            console.log(now);
        }
    });
}


myFun();
myFun();
```

If I call it twice, the second time `now` remains fixed at 100. I tried to solve like this:

```
myFun = () => {
    $('.test').animate({ now: 100}, {
        duration: 1000,
        complete: function() {
            now = 0;
        },
        step: function(now) {
            console.log(now);
        }
    });
}
```

but it doesn't work. How do I reset `now`?

(In general I need to repeat an animation with the step function)

Answer (score 0):

There are two things you will have to look at. First, you can't trigger a `myFun` without waiting for the `animation` to complete for the first run.

And that is why I made `myFun` return a `Promise` and resolve it in `complete` function.

The second issue, I do not think that there is any way to reset the step without running animate again and reset it to 0 again.

And that is why I added another `animate` that will reset the step to 0.

Have a look below:

```js
myFun = (t) => {
   return new Promise((r)=> {
    $('.test').animate({ now: 0},{
    complete:()=> {
    $('.test').animate({ now: 100}, {
        duration: 1000,
        complete: function() {
            now = 0;
            r();
        },
        step: function(now) {
            console.log(t, ":", now);
        }
    });
   }})
   })
}

myFun(1).then(x=>myFun(2) );
```

```css
.test {
  background: red;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 3px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
<div class="test"></div>
```